# GCP permission to list GCS objects but forbidden to download

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-iam, google-cloud-iam

I have some sensitive data saved on GCS bucket. Now, the requirement is to generate V4 signed urls of the GCS objects and allow only certain users to download the objects who possesses the url. However, other users should only be able to see that object is present on GCS but should not be allowed to download the same.

For this, we have created a service account which has `Storage Admin` role (yes, we can further restrict this) and same is used to generate the urls. However, the issue is, any user who is having `storage object viewer` role, is able to download the object which we do not want. Is there any way we can restrict all other users apart from service account to download the object?

Also, I tried creating a custom role which was given `storage.buckets.list` and `storage.objects.get` or `storage.objects.list` permissions, and then assign that role to the desired users but in both the cases, user was able to download the files. Apart from these 2 permissions, i could not find any other permission which could restrict the download.

Answer (score 1):

The IAM policy applied to your project defines the actions that users can take on all objects or buckets within your project. An IAM policy applied to a single bucket defines the actions that users can take on that specific bucket and objects within it.

1.Create an IAM policy for  your buckets that gives one user administrative control of that bucket. Meanwhile, you can add another user to your project-wide IAM policy that gives that user the ability to view objects in any bucket of your project.

2.Go to your bucket and define the members and the assigned roles, which grant members the ability to perform actions in Cloud Storage as well as Google Cloud more generally.

here is the link from GCP docs: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/collaboration